# curvature of objects on a 2-d digital image

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

For a 2-d digital grey-scale image, I assume that any object, such as lines, edges, contours, is just 2-d stuff, isn't it? Or since each pixel of any object has a grey-scale value, which makes them 3-d?

I just read an [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform#Eliminating_edge_responses), which tells that for a point in the image, it has **2 principal curvature**, which confuses me, because if any object on the image is just 2-d, how could it 2 principal curvatures, right?

Furthermore, what's the relationship between principal curvatures and *Hessian matrix*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be right that the $D$ in that article is just 2D image data; i.e. a real function on some 2-dimensional domain. When they talk about the curvature, they're considering the curvature of the *graph* of the function $D$; i.e. the surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ given by $G(x,y) = (x,y,D(x,y))$.

For such a surface, the second fundamental form is proportional to the Hessian of $D$, and thus the principal curvatures are proportional to the eigenvalues of the Hessian. Here's a sketch of this calculation using subscript notation for all derivatives.

By definition, the second fundamental form is $$A_{ij} = G_{ij} \cdot \nu$$ where $\nu$ is the upwards unit normal vector $$\nu = \frac{G_x \times G_y}{\Vert G_x \times G_y \Vert} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + D_x^2 + D_y^2}} (- D_x, - D_y, 1).$$

Differentiating $G$ gives $$G_{ij} = (0,0,D_{ij}).$$ Taking the dot product with the unit normal then gives $$A_{ij} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + D_x^2 + D_y^2}}D_{ij}.$$ Notice that the matrix $D_{ij}$ is exactly the Hessian of $D$.

(Note that the sign can vary for two reasons - the choice of orientation of normal vector and the sign convention used in the definition of $A$.)

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem, I don't understand why the Hessian's eigenvalues are the principal curvatures.

Comment: @loganecolss: Actually my claim is flawed - this is only true at critical points of $D$. I'll expand my post with some details.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't get it that why the second fundamental form is $A_{ij}=\nabla_jG\cdot\nabla_iv$? And by $A_{ij}$, do you mean there are more than one second fundamental form, which depends on the choice of $x,y$ coordinates?

Comment: @loganecolss: $A_{ij}$ is the $(i,j)$th entry of the matrix $A$. What is your definition of the second fundamental form?

Comment: Well, I only know the definition of second fundamental form from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_fundamental_form

Comment: @loganecolss: rewrote it starting from wikipedia's definition

Comment: Thank you so much, so $A_{ij}$'s value is determined by both $D_{ij}$ and the first-order derivatives $u_x,u_y$, right? When $u_x = u_y = 0$, I can understand $Hessian$ determines the local curvatures, otherwise, $u_x,u_y$ still have some affect on $A_{ij}$, although the ratio of the two eigenvalues doesn't change

Comment: @loganecolss: correct. For some reason I used both $D$ and $u$ to mean the same thing, I'll correct that.

Comment: So, if $D_x，D_y \ne 0$, we cannot just use Hessian matrix without $D_x,D_y$ to estimate the local curvature, can we?

Comment: @loganecolss: that's right. All the Hessian can give you by itself is the ratio and directions of the principal curvatures.

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience, you're so kind ;-)