# Laplacian on ${\bf R}^2$ and mean curvature

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry

Consider a function $f$ on ${\bf R}^2$ whose critical point is origin.

Then Gaussian curvature of graph of $f$ at origin is determinant of ${\rm Hess} \ f$ and Mean curvature is trace of ${\rm Hess} \ f$. Here $\Delta f $ is a mean curvature. In general is there some relation ?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you want to remove the criticial point assumption?

Comment: Yes can we rule out critical point assumption ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general expression for the second fundamental form of the graph of $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ is $$ A = \frac1{\sqrt{1+|\nabla f|^2}} \mathrm{Hess}f;$$ you can find the derivation in e.g. my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/481311/curvature-of-objects-on-a-2-d-digital-image/481829#481829).

Thus the mean curvature is in general given by $$H = \mathrm{tr} A =  \frac{ \mathrm{tr}_g \mathrm{Hess}f}{\sqrt{1+|\nabla f|^2}}$$ where $g$ is the metric of the surface.

Note that the Hessian and the trace are taken in two different geometries - the Hessian is taken in $\mathbb R^2$, but the trace is taken in the surface - I forgot about this before and incorrectly wrote the trace as the Laplacian. Unfortunately I don't think such a neat expression exists for this - you can certainly write the metric in terms of the derivatives of $f$, but it'll be ugly. See e.g. [Mathworld's page on the Monge patch](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MongePatch.html).

Comment: I think that $H = \frac{En + Gl-2Fm}{2(EG-F^2)}$.

Comment: @HeeKwonLee: You're right, I made a mistake. Edited.